# Defining a join relationship outside of Hash structure - CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I am looking to perform a join relationship for an ability permissions using CanCanCan.

Initially, I was given this:

```
can :read, Block, page: { is_published: true }
```

Given the info from the [docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities#hash-of-conditions), it says I can define them as a Hash. However, I have to refactor this to check if another field on `page`, `published_at` is either present or `nil`.

Here is my new block:

```
can :read, Block, ["pages.published_at IS NOT NULL"] do |block|
  block.page.published_at.present?
end
```

Essentially that is the gist of what I want. However, when performing a SQL statement check, it will say `pages` does not exist - which is expected because I have not performed the join.

I am wondering if you have to create a scope on `Block` that handles the joins. Or maybe place the joins in the `can` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I read further into the docs where it talks about [Block Conditions with Scopes](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks/d45bda85c221798d0aff366f9558c943552e3b64#block-conditions-with-scopes).

So I proceeded with this example:

```
 1 # Block.rb
 2 scope :owned_by_published_page, -> { joins(:page).where.not(pages: { published_at: nil }) }
 3
 4 # ability.rb
 5 can :read, Block, Block.owned_by_published_page do |block|
 6   block.page.published_at.present?
 7 end
```

This would work, but after I ran into a couple more problems which is highlighted in the CanCanCan docs:

> You cannot use this with multiple can definitions that match the same action and model since it is not possible to combine them. An exception will be raised when that is the case.

Of course I have a couple more permissions being configured that are unable to merge together. In this case, I just proceeded to do a `cannot` statement to just handle the inverse.

`cannot :read, Block, page: { published_at: nil }`

This is enough for what I am looking for.